# Traditional (standard) checkout (step by step page)

Tags: magento, checkout

Here is my query in magento.
I don't want to use onepage checkout & I want traditional checkout flow in magento. i.e. new page for new step.

For that i have changed below setting:
Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout
Enable Onepage Checkout => No
&
Admin > System > Configuration > Shipping Settings
Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses => No

But in front side checkout button is not visible in cart page.
Please guide me.
[Screenshot for cart](http://tinypic.com/r/2ypfe3b/5)

Comment: One of the most compelling reasons to need this classic style checkout is mobile websites that might lack AJAX support.

Comment: I know this is old, but wanted to also add...a very compelling reason to need the classic checkout is when you have a punch-out to another site, where you have to pass a return url. For example, checkout payment options which need to interact with the checkout page.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it seems that there is really only one built-in checkout, the one you are seeing.  I thought that by disabling One-Page Checkout I would in effect be *enabling* the other, but no...  It seems the admin option is better paraphrased as "Would you like checkout *at all* or would you like to *disable* checkout?"

I can't see why you would want to do such a thing, or when it comes into play, perhaps when you are implementing other checkout extensions?

At any rate, it seems that the stock, out-of-the-box functionality is to live with it the way you see it, or explore modifying behavior through custom extensions.

Answer (score -1):

here's a way

```
Admin > System > Configuration > Checkout Enable Onepage Checkout => **Yes**
```

Comment: If i set it as 'Yes' then checkout page will be in one page. I want each individual page for each step.

Comment: cool :) i want a lot of things as well but you forgot to describe what checkout method should be used if you disable the OPC (as this is the only available by default)

Comment: Actually i want "Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses"=>"No" and front side it should work for only one address.. But front side checkout link is not visible after this change..You mean magento doesn't provide standard multi page checkout by default?

Comment: please update your question to reflect the real situation you want/need cause in the comments you are asking different stuff

Comment: I think my questions and comments are asking same thing..may be language gap.. Anyways no help.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: just tested on clean installation and setting OPC = yes and ASMA = no works as expected

Comment: don't make "Allow Shipping to Multiple Addresses" to No

Comment: I agree with VibhaJ, the option is totally pointless, and there was no language gap, Anton just was not paying attention.
If one page checkout is the only checkout method, then there should not be a damn option to disable it...it is a completely pointless option.
All modern carts have a one-page and multi-page option. This is a big fat FAIL on Magento's part.