# Magento multi-step checkout

Tags: magento, checkout

The problem is that when i disable One page checkout, the Proceed button is gone. My installation is 1.9.2 Community Edition. I've tried to enable that button from link.phtml but get the message "The Unilateral payment transaction is disabled"

Comment: You will need to provide more information. The question is unclear. Show some code to start with.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:** You don't. What you do is disabeling the Magento Module `Mage_Checkout_Onepage`

Magento comes with one stock checkout, the infamous `OnePage`. There are many distributers of neat (and shitty) checkouts, mostly called `OneStepCheckout` or `SingleStepCheckout`. I suggest you find yourself a good one and buy it, because a decent checkout is a major difference between gaining and losing customers.

This guy had a similar [question about disabeling the magento onepage checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060225/traditional-standard-checkout-step-by-step-page)

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is how i do it. I log in into admin panel, than i do:
1) System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Enable one page checkout "No" (because i wanna use multi-step checkout option)
[Admin checkout settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pIbY.jpg)

2) Add some product to cart and when i view content of the cart and proceed to checkout the button " Proceed to checkout" is missing. 
[Frontend checkout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLBW2.jpg)